# Flutter BoxDecoration’s background color overrides the Container's background color, why?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, background-color, flutter-container

I have a Flutter Container widget and I defined a color for it (pink), but for some reason, the color in BoxDecoration overrides it (green). Why?

```
new Container(
  color: Colors.pink,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Container’s `color` is shorthand for BoxDecoration’s `color`, so BoxDecoration's `color` in the Container's `decoration` property overrides its Container's `color`.

Comment: i want to give blue color for border and amber for container background color, how can i do?

Comment: You can achieve like this ```decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.yellow,
        border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,)
      ),``` @Kamlesh

Answer (score 28):

##### Problem:

You can't use `color` and `decoration` at the same time. From [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/Container.html):

> The `color` and `decoration` arguments cannot both be supplied, since it would potentially result in the decoration drawing over the background color. To supply a decoration with a color, use `decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)`.

---

##### Solutions:

- Use only `color`:

  ```dart
  Container(
    color: Colors.red
  )
  ```
- Use only `decoration` and provide `color` here:

  ```dart
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)
  )
  ```

Answer (score 5):

only set background color use this code

```
new Container(
  color: Colors.pink,
  
);
```

if set background color with radius or shape then use color inside decoration

```
 Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17)),
child:SizeBox());
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter team says that color property in BoxDecoration() is quite frequently used in applying background color to Container widget. As such they have put a separate shorthand for color property in Container widget. So, when we use both color property and BoxDecoration() color property in same Container widget, an assertion will be thrown as follows:

```
Cannot provide both a color and a decoration
The color argument is just a shorthand for "decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: color)".
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically in Flutter it is not allowed you cannot give color to both container and boxdecortion at the same time
in the below provided i have commented out one of the color which in my case is container which will help u solve your error.

```
Container(
          height: 150,
          // color: Colors.red,  
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black, //assign either here or to the container
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),))
```