# Flutter Container: cannot provide both a color and a decoration

Tags: flutter, dart, background-color, flutter-container, decoration

I want to draw a border around my container and have the background be colored.

```
Widget bodyWidget() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    child: Text("Flutter"),
  );
}
```

But when I try this I get the error

> Cannot provide both a color and a decoration
>   The color argument is just a shorthand for "decoration: new BoxDecoration(color:
>   color)".

How is this solved?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Remove the `color` parameter from the Container and add it to the BoxDecoration:

```
Widget bodyWidget() {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    child: Text("Flutter"),
  );
}
```

[image]

If you check the [Container source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart) you can see that the `color` parameter is just used to set the BoxDecoration color if the decoration is null.

```
decoration = decoration ?? (color != null ? BoxDecoration(color: color) : null),
```

The error you got is just a helpful reminder of that. Otherwise you would get a strange override ([as was apparently the case in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724567/flutter-boxdecoration-s-background-color-overrides-the-containers-background-co)) or you might not even notice the bug.

Answer (score 1):

When using the **decoration** property, ensure to place the **color** property within the decoration and not outside.

you can use like this:

```
 Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.red,
          );
```